# Mxs: Collect Border edges of Mesh

Tags: mesh, 3dsmax, maxscript

I'm trying to collect the edges of all borders (open edges) in my mesh and store these edges in an array. More specifically I would like to seperate the edges into as many arrays as there are borders in the mesh.

Example: we have a mesh with 2 holes in it (see attached files for an image of the mesh), therefore it has 2 borders, I'd like the script to produce an array with 2 subarrays, 1 subarray for each hole/'open edge loop'. Image of this mesh: [test mesh, vertex numbers indicated in blue/purple, edge numbers indicated in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL76y.png)

If anyone could tell me what the proper way to collect the edges into an array is that'd be very much appreciated. If you know/can think of a good way of separating the edges into their respective sub arrays (corresponding to the holes/border in the mesh) please let me know.

Images:

[open edge loops indicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBHYY.png)

[desired result/output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMO5M.png)

What I've tried:

I've tried selecting the open edges using the command

```
 polyOp.getOpenEdges $
```

I did get this working for selecting the open edges, unfortunately I was not able to 'get' the edge numbers of said open edges using this command since the result of the getOpenEdges command is a bitarray([here](http://forums.cgsociety.org/archive/index.php?t-478659.html) and [here](https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2016/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_B40F84EA_5F19_45B6_AA7C_0ADC77708BBE_htm)).

I've written some pseudocode which should work for seperating the edges into their respective subarrays after all open edges have been stored in an array:

--NOTE: open_edges is the array in which all open/border edges of the mesh are stored

```
i = 0; edge_found = true
while open_edges.count > 0 do(
    current_loop = #()
    while edge_found == true do(
        i += 1
        if i==1 do( append current_loop open_edges[1]; Deleteitem open_edges 1 )

        -- Select 2nd vertex of current_loop[-1]
        -- Find edge in 'open_edges' which has this vertex
        --if(no edge is found)then( edge_found = false )
        --else(  
            -- Append the found edge to 'current_loop'
            -- Remove the found edge from 'open_edges'
            --)
        ) --end while edge_found == true do(
    ) --end while open_edges.count > 0 do(
```

If you spot a mistake in my code/approach for separating the edges into their respective sub arrays (corresponding to the holes/border in the mesh) or can think of a better/more efficient method of performing this process please let me know.

Thank you!

Note: in the attached image: 'edge_and_vertex_nums.png' I've indicated the edge numbers in red and the vertex numbers in blue/purple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
You can also simply compare the firstHole array with allOpenEdges and remove the duplicates.

```
allOpenEdges = (polyop.getOpenEdges $) as array
firstHole = (polyop.getBorderFromEdge $ allOpenEdges[1]) as array

select $
subobjectlevel = 2
polyop.setEdgeSelection $ firstHole
subobjectLevel = 3
max select invert
secondHole = (polyop.getedgeselection $) as array
subobjectLevel = 0

format "count1: %, count2: %\n" firstHole.count secondHole.count
```